# Livecycle Designer: JavaScript - find an element by name and position from the root

Tags: javascript, livecycle

I need some advice how to select an element by position no matter where it is in the document. For example let's say we have something like this:

```
Document    
 Subform
   a
   b
   a
 Subform
   b
   a
   c
 Subform
   a
   b
   a
   a
....
```

Is it possible to check the value for example of the fifth element "a" in the document (from the beginning) no matter in which Subform it is? Something like `if (xfa.resolveNode(Document.Subform[*].a[5]).rawValue === "y") {do something}`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use a generic selector like `document.querySelectorAll('div')`. It will return the list of all the elements matching the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning this is a Javascript WAY not a livecycle solution ( take care ).

Your question is quite interesting, because i suppose you want to wrap all of that subforms and check at once the value is "y" inside the input named "a" im not sure if that exists.

My solution for that will be to iterate over document.forms because we don't now their name.

The next will be create a map definition in which form appears that expected value.

```
let hasExpectedValue = [].slice.call(document.forms).map((form)=>{
    return form.a.value === "y";
})
```

Then we can iterate and use the index which was true and do some stuff.

May exists other way and optimised to wrap it all and iterate over them.